Renaming (moving) images from DCIM/Camera to another directory (created by other app) in Android
I'm trying to create an app for myself for categorizing my previously taken photos in external storage.
I'd like to move them to specified folders without any success. I'm a bit lost in what should I use here? A pendingintent? Use createWriteRequest() method? I haven't found any step-by-step tutorial pointing this topic. I've read I have to ask permission file-by-file to have permission to modify it. But how other apps do this without any complication? (Like in TotalCommander I can easily rename a file) Could you show a simple code how to handle this?
SDK 33
Android 14
Manifest:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

I'm storing in lastModifiedTime variable a reference time code.
And tried a simple rename process to the same dir first:
Activity:
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DCIM/Camera";
        Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles(File::isFile);
        if (files != null){
            for (File file : files){
                if (file.lastModified() > lastModifiedTime){
                    Log.d("Files", file.getName());
                    File newfile = new File(path+"/"+file.getName()+"_2");
                    Log.d("Files", "new: "+newfile.getName());
                    if (file.renameTo(newfile)){
                        Log.d("Files", "OK");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Files", "ERROR");
                    };
                }
            }
        }


You need to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as TotalCommander do.
See Android document:
Manage all files on a storage device.
